# 'Brew unlink node' error

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I am going to downgrade the current node version to v6.13.0 on MacOS. So, I run this command first.

```
brew unlink node
```

But I am having this error.

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
```

Let me know how I fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

If `node -v` works, then you should check to see where node is installed with `which node`.

I would recommend using nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage different versions of node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Node is installed to this path. /usr/local/bin/node
And node -v works
Then, what do I have to do with homebrew

Comment: Looks like it may have just been installed with the .pkg which makes it harder to uninstall. My recommendation is to follow some instructions like http://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/ and once it is uninstalled install nvm. That way it's easy to install/uninstall and then use different versions.